# How do I get an Nvidia Geforce 310M working?

Tags: compiz, graphics, unity-2d, nvidia-optimus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I have NVIDIA GeForce 310M (Hybrid) Graphics in my Samsung QX 410s02 laptop. I installed Ubuntu 11.10. Before installing mesa-utils,in the section "System Info", the graphics driver was listed as unkown, but now it displays Intel® Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2 and the experience in Standard.

And I am not being able to use all the compiz or unity effects. The nvidia graphics card is based on optimus technology. I installed the proprietary softwares and configured the nvidia settings using `sudo nvidia-xconfig` and when i restarted the computer, it got stuck somewhere an like anarc(h)........so i again installed Ubuntu 11.10. I searched for the problems, and they said that nvidia optimus is not supported.

Now, i want to know, is there any process to enable all the compiz and unity effects in my computer. Which graphics card should i use(nvidia or intel) and what is the process or commands do i need to follow?? please help me.....

Answer (score 0):

you need [bumblebee](https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/stable). You can call this optimus (unofficial) for linux. To install it in ubuntu

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee
```

Please visit the bumblebee link above.

Comment: i installed the bumblebee but still i am not being able to use the compiz effects.....I enabled the Ubuntu Unity Plugin but it is not working. The size of the icon is still same though i resized it to 32 px. Also the opacity is same. None of the compiz effects are working. What should i do to use all the effects of unity??

Comment: Check your bios settings and see if you can set the video card to use the discrete graphics only. This is not available on all bioses, but if it is there you will have the options of:

    Optimus

    Discrete

    Integrated.

Choose Discrete.

Comment: There is no such any options in my BIOS. I cannot choose my default graphics. Is there any other way to use all compiz settings??